# Oracle 11gR2 failed on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, oracle-database

I am installing Oracle 11gR2 on CentOS 7. I have the packages installed, I have the kernel parameter set but still its not working. Here are the images.
[Installation Image[image: ][1]]

[image: Package Query Result]

[image: Kernel Parameters]

Comment: Please don't paste images/screenshots when text will do.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the `kernel.sem` parameters separately:

```
 kernel.semsml=250
 kernel.semmns=32000
 kernel.semopm=100
 kernel.semmni=128
```

Oracle is a bit silly when it comes to detecting the settings, afaik, YMMV, but I have always had to set them separately ...

Comment: I added the lines in sysctl and this was the result '[root@server1 oracle]# /sbin/sysctl -p
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 536870912
kernel.shmmni = 4096
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/semsml: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/semmns: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/semopm: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/semmni: No such file or directory
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default = 262144'